# display:block to display:none and back makes embedded SVG elements disappear unless hosted locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't get SVGs in <embed>s or <object>s to reappear after toggling to and from `display:block` unless they are hosted locally (referenced from `file://`). Example:

```
<head>
<style>
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function toggle() {
    console.log("toggling");
    var con = document.getElementById('container');
    console.log(con.style.display);
    if(con.style.display == 'block') {
        con.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        con.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
<div id="container" style="display:block">
    <embed src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Eiim/4611-2019-scouting/resources/svg/CargoShip.svg">
    <p>I'm some text!</p>
</div>
<h1 onclick="toggle()">Toggle it all!</h1>
</body>
```

I've only tested on Chrome 71, but it seems to be strange behavior. From what I can tell, there's no difference in the DOM before and after the toggle. I also attempted embedding some text (specifically, https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/frc1418/FRCNewTab/newtab.html) and it still showed the text, but unusually would not let me interact after the toggles. Is this just a Chrome bug, or a bug in my code? Is there a workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have tested using img. it seems to work fine.

Comment: That's a known quirk in webkit (safari + Blink). They don't do it with an <iframe> though. Han I was pretty sure I already answered that... Her is [one related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374155/requesting-full-screen-refreshes-data-html-canvas-in-object-tag/52380441#52380441), but not good enough for a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webkit browsers indeed do unload the document loaded by these two elements when either removed from the DOM or hidden.

What really happens here is unclear, but sounds a lot like a bug, where they do reload a new document every time the element is shown (and in Blink with a bigger bug where it is reloaded in an infinite loop while hidden).

```js
obj.onload = emb.onload = e => console.log(e.target.nodeName, 'loaded');
```

```css
input:checked ~ object, input:checked ~ embed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>Toggle display</label><input type="checkbox">
<object id="obj" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg"></object>
<embed id="emb" type="image/svg+xml" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg">
```

That's a quirk in there configuration, and there is not much you can do to prevent it.

However, note that they don't do it with an `<iframe>`. While it will require a bit more work for styling it, it will also allow you to access the document, without it being unloaded for no reasons.

```js
frame.onload = e => console.log(e.target.nodeName, 'loaded');
```

```css
input:checked ~ iframe {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>Toggle display</label><input type="checkbox">
<iframe id="frame" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated with embed. Your syntax is wrong

```
      <head>
        <style>
        div {
          border: 1px solid black;
          margin: 5px;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script>
        function toggle() {
            console.log("toggling");
            var con = document.getElementById('container');
            console.log(con.style.display);
            if(con.style.display == 'block') {
                con.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                con.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
        </script>
        <div id="container" style="display:block">
            <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Eiim/4611-2019-scouting/resources/svg/CargoShip.svg">

 <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Eiim/4611-2019-scouting/resources/svg/CargoShip.svg">
            <p>I'm some text!</p>
        </div>
        <h1 onclick="toggle()">Toggle it all!</h1>
        </body>
```

Comment: And then you don't have access to the inner doc.

Comment: As @Kaiido said, that does prevent me from accessing the svg to change it on the fly, which is why I didn't use <img>s in the first place, but I can certainly work around it. Any idea why <embed>s don't work?

Comment: No @Raahul: *Keep in mind that most modern browsers have deprecated and removed support for browser plug-ins, so relying upon <embed> is generally not wise if you want your site to be operable on the average user's browser* : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed)

Comment: @soulshined Except that all browsers support SVG natively, so there are no plugins involved.